# Were there any rewards for going on a crusade aside from being forgiven for one's biblical sins?

Tags: crusades

I might have misunderstood this, but from what I gathered the main selling point/reward for going on the various crusades, was absolution for your sins: it didn´t matter what someone had done, if that person went on a crusade to the holy lands, that person would be forgiven for all the biblical sins that person had committed.

My question is, could going on a crusade also be used to clear away any misdeeds one might have committed as in once one returned from the crusade it wouldn´t matter what misdeeds or crimes (short of actual treason of the kind that would get you executed) one had committed? Once returned, were people considered absolved of those misdeeds and crimes?

Or was that not how the crusades worked?

Also, was it more like once someone went on a crusade (unless the person was a king) the person was expected to remain in the holy lands until the person died?

Or it only gave the person absolution for their sins, but any other problems you might have had crime, a scandal, debt or whatever didn´t go away and still waited for the person once the person got back?

Comment: In ancient and medieval times, participation in warfare was not exactly a matter of personal choice for the common population. In many countries, including my own, military service was mandatory until relatively recently.

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: I'm not sure what "biblical sins" are.   Are you asking if Crusade could clear civil crimes?  or scandals?

Comment: @Lucian Military service was only introduced in Western Europe at the end of the 18th century. Before that, soldiers were usually fighting for money or for loot (though occasionally armies would also *pressgang* random men into service). See e.g. Landsknechte or, before that, Swiss mercenaries. Or *Free* *companies* in France.

Comment: @MCW It did no go like that. Monarchs rarely had absolute power, it was always contested by church and higher nobility, sometimes by their own siblings etc... Also, monarchs were often those who called up volunteers for crusade.  Returning crusader would have a lot of "social credit"  and prestige.

Comment: @rs.29 and maybe some loot.

Comment: I just watched *They Shall Not Grow Old*. The opening few minutes have a lot of insight into why young men sign up for wars. It's profitable, exciting, guaranteed work glorified (at least before you go over!) by elders, youth, and love interest alike, and few knew what they were getting into... I wonder how many of those reasons were just as true in the 11th century.

Comment: It was not 'forgive everything magic', it was only a plenary indulgence https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07783a.htm (you have to confess it before hand, must abhor your sin, it does not take the guilt, only the penalty in purgatory, etc) There were (and are) much easier ways to gain an indulgence than crusading, it would not be rational to go there just because of that. Reasons may be adventure, gains, social pressure, sense of duty, being ordered to go, or just because too much was lost to muslims and they were afraid to be the next victim.

Comment: And european kings and other rulers were not expected to remain there forever, they returned to their lands (e.g. St Louis IX and Richard the Lionheart). Maybe you mean the people chosen to be counts and rulers of the newly formed crusader states. Somebody must rule, somebody must stay, right?

Comment: @MCW I am mostly talking about the common understanding of the crusades ala If you go down there your sins are forgiven and you will be secured a place in paradise. 
From my understanding of this, religion was a much more ingrained part of peoples lives back then so a pardon for sins and be promised a place in heaven no matter what you had done, might have been enough back then for the people able to go on a crusade to go.

Comment: @MCW To me though (and this may just be my modern day thinking that shines through here) that just doesn´t seem enough, since going to the holy lands back then wasn´t exactly something you just did and it needed proper planing and supplies, which couldn´t have been cheap 

So in order for someone to go on a crusade the rewards for doing so, must have been greater then just you gain absolution for your sins and a place in paradise when you die. 

And more of a you go on a crusade and that scandal you caused we´ll just forget about it, same with that huge debt you owe or something like that.

Comment: and then there's all the people who were simply conscripted and didn't have much if any say in where they were going.

Comment: @Gridlock In those times, a guaranteed spot in paradise actually _could_ be enough easily. I once heard a comparison by a historian along the lines of, a meeting between a person from the middle ages and person from today would be like a meeting between an alien and a human - because the two mindsets would be so radically different.

Comment: @Gridlock Also, not every crusade and every crusader started their journey well prepared. On several occasions, a charismatic preacher in the marketplace was all it took to enthuse people enough to just go and take off to where they thought Jerusalem might be (see [popular crusades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_crusades)).

Comment: @Gridlock In general, it seems to me that your image of the crusades is much more uniform and homogenous than those wars actually were. Many crusaders had many different motives and expectations what might await them in the "holy lands". Maybe you were the younger son of a local noble who couldn't hope to inherit your fathers position - in the holy lands there might be a plot of land for you (though that very rarely worked out). Maybe you were a peasant, and you heard a rumor that the pope promised to set you free in exchange for participating (true or not). And so on and so forth...

Comment: Notoriety upon your return, much how soldiers, regardless of character, are lauded today when they come home, seems to me to be at least the second most powerful motivator to convince a man to go to war. The other being pain of punishment if they are awol.

Answer (score 10):

There were indeed other incentives offered by both Church and State to individuals joining the crusades. What was offered was more often in the form of assurances of protection for the status and household/families of the individuals.

Suspension of debt payments, termination of interest payments, protection from lawsuits, and three year payment plans for debts after a two year hiatus are among the offerings.

The 1901 book *Urban and the Crusaders*, edited by [Dana Carleton Munro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dana_Carleton_Munro), has a section on [Privileges of the Crusaders](https://books.google.com/books?id=ljYNAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Dana%20C.%20Munro,%20%22Urban%20and%20the%20Crusaders%22,&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZwbHTxfjzAhVdnWoFHcn-D3AQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=privileges&f=false). In this section he has gathered several relevant documents translated from various popes and kings concerning the types of concessions and protections offered to those individuals who 'take the cross'.

A web friendly version of this information can be found at the site [Medieval Sourcebook: Evolution of Crusader Privileges, 1095-1270](https://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/source/cde-privs.asp) at Fordham.edu.

Some excerpts (bold points mine):

First, the religious aspect, [Council of Clermont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Clermont) 1095:

> *If any one through devotion alone, and not for the sake of honor or
> gain, goes to Jerusalem to free the church of God, **the journey itself**
> shall **take the place of all penance.***

[Pope Eugenius III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Eugene_III), 1146 (second crusade) expanded the incentives package :

> *We have also commanded that **their wives and children, their property
> and possessions, shall be under the protection of the holy church**, of
> ourselves, of the archbishops, bishops and other prelates of the
> church of God. Moreover, we ordain by our apostolic authority that
> until their return or death is fully proven, **no law suit** shall be
> instituted hereafter in regard to any property of which they were in
> peaceful possession when they took the cross.**
> ...
> *Those who with pure hearts enter upon such a sacred journey and who
> are in debt **shall pay no interest**. And if they or others for them are
> bound by oath or promise to pay interest, we free them by our
> apostolic authority*

The next section is from a decree by [King Phillip Augustus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_II_of_France) of France, in 1188

> *That bishops, prelates, and clerks of the conventual churches, and
> knights who have taken the cross, shall have a **respite of two years** -
> dating from the first feast of All Saints after the departure of the
> king - **in paying the debts** which they owed to Jews or Christians
> before the king took the cross; that is, on the first feast of All
> Saints the creditors shall have a third of the debt, and on the
> following feast of All Saints a second third of the debt, and on the
> third feast of All Saints the last third of the debt. Also, for each
> one, from the day on which he takes the cross, **interest on debts
> previously contracted shall cease**.*

I don't want to copy paste the entire page over, but this point may be poignant concerning individual incentives (same decree):

> *If a knight, **who is the legitimate heir, son, or son-in-law** of a
> knight not taking the cross, or of a widow, and who is under the
> jurisdiction of his father or mother, takes the cross, **his father or
> mother shall have a respite from their debts**, in accordance with the
> above ordinance.*

This section would seem to indicated a son joining the crusades in the name of his elders would get the same protections applied ***to his parents debts***.

One last note, since part of the question was referring to forgiveness for crimes. A privilege offered by [Louis IX of France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_IX_of_France) in 1270 seems to offer some limited protection to crusaders for criminal actions by turning them over to be judged within the church instead of the secular courts:

> *If the king, or a count, or a baron, or any lord who has the right of
> jurisdiction in his land, arrests a clerk, or crusader, or any man of
> religion, even if he is a layman, the lord ought to **deliver him to the
> holy church, whatever may be his crime**. And if the clerk has committed
> a crime for which the penalty is death by hanging, and is not
> tonsured, the secular justice ought to try him. But if be is tonsured
> and wears the habit of a clerk, even if he is a thief, no confession,
> no answer that he may make, can injure him, for he is not before his
> regular judges; and any confession made by one who is not before his
> regular judges has no value, according to the law written in the
> Decretals.*

Some more details in the book and web page, but this gets the main idea across concerning the form of *some* of the incentives and protections offered to those that joined the crusades.

Comment: Not paying interest, or covering debts, etc... would you describe that as "payment" more or less? Like how modern soldiers actually take a salary? And were the debt holders just forced to eat it, or did the Church or other authorities actually cover them, in part or whole?

Comment: Since most of these were actually listed as deferments, I think they still would be more aptly considered incentives.  They were essentially guarantees that the status quo would be maintained while the knight was off crusading. Much like today when National guard soldiers are called to active duty and their civilians jobs are supposed to be protected while they are gone. The cancellation of interest would be a direct financial gain, however.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that they were *deferred*, not cancelled.